# sklearn nearest neighbor runtime: construction vs lookup

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, runtime, nearest-neighbor

Suppose I have a 2D numpy array of size roughly 4000 by 10. Let's say I consider each row as a point in 10-dimensional space and would like to compute, say, the 5-nearest neighbor for each point. I ran the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import time
A = np.random.rand(4000, 10)
t1 = time.time()
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors = 5, algorithm = 'kd_tree').fit(A)
t2 = time.time()
distance, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(A)
t3 = time.time()
print('time taken for step1: fitting is:', t2 - t1)
print('time taken for step2: retrieving data is:', t3 - t2)
```

The result is

```
time taken for step1: fitting is: 0.009654521942138672
time taken for step2: retrieving data is: 0.3108406066894531
```

My first question: why is getting the distances/indices arrays taking much longer than fitting. To my understanding, fitting is the process of building the model(computing distances, sorting through the computed distance), while getting distances/indices is simply reading data from the model. It is quite the opposite to my intuition that step 2 is taking much more time. Which part of my understanding is incorrect?

My second question is, if I just want the indices from the model, i.e. for each point, indices of the 5 points that are closest, not the distances, is there any way to make step 2 faster?

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding is not quite right. The relative speed of construction vs lookup depends on the algorithm. [The documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) says this about your choice of K-D tree (my emphasis):

> The **construction** of a KD tree is very fast: because partitioning is performed only along the data axes, no D-dimensional distances need to be computed. Once constructed, the nearest neighbor **[lookup]** of a query point can be determined with only O[log(N)] distance computations. Though the KD tree approach is very fast for low-dimensional (D < 20) neighbors searches, it becomes inefficient as D grows very large

Comment: Thanks! I missed that part in the documentation.